# program will not stop sleeping computer

Tags: c#, sleep, suspend

My application is set to go to sleep when a notification balloontip is clicked and this process is all looped.  This works, but when I awaken my computer, it goes to sleep shortly thereafter (this has a slight time delay, but as this takes as long as it normally takes for my computer to go to sleep, I wouldn't give this any consideration).  I've removed this snippet from my overall program, and the program then works perfectly fine, making me think that there's something in this code that makes the computer go to sleep.  Furthermore, in case one of the flags controlling the loops is reset, I've reset those flags, but the problem keeps happening.  In case (for some strange reason) the boolean operators were impacting it, I've changed them in all the combinations I could, and it *still* didn't work!  I've tried adding in a command to prevent the computer from going to sleep, but that didn't work either.  Any suggestions?  Much appreciated.

```
for (; ; )
{
    bool for3 = false;
    for (; ; )
    {
        notifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip(10000);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
        Application.DoEvents();
        if (loopVariable)
            for3 = true;
        if (for3) break;
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(60000);
    }
    loopVariable = false;
    for3 = false;
    DateTime timeOnSleep = DateTime.Now;
    Application.SetSuspendState(PowerState.Suspend, false, false);//this is the annoying code
        DateTime timeOnWake = DateTime.Now;
        TimeSpan time = timeOnWake - timeOnSleep;
        var minutes = time.TotalMinutes;
        Math.Round(time.TotalMinutes, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
        double dMins = minutes;
        try
        {
            int iNumber = System.Convert.ToInt32(dMins);
        }
        catch (System.OverflowException)
        {
            if (dMins >= 40)
                break;
        }
    }
private static bool loopVariable = false;

void notifyIcon_BalloonTipClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    loopVariable = true;
}
```

Comment: Instead of making us read malfunctioning code, how about describing what you are trying to accomplish here.

Comment: I'm trying to make the computer go to sleep when the notifyIcon is clicked (which works), but when I awaken the computer, it goes back to sleep again whilst I am still running the program.

Comment: What's this weird loop all about?

Comment: Also, where is your listed code being called from?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the loop you are referring to is the looping sleep event, which by rights should not be occurring.  As I describe above, the computer continually goes to sleep when I awaken it: something that should not be happening.  Instead, it should either break the first for loop shown above, or return to the beginning of that loop.  This code is being called just after the form is created ie straight after InitializeComponent();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you find yourself using doevents, you're likely doing something wrong. If you needed to run a loop like that use `do {}` rather than `for (;;)`. In any case, you don't need either of those things. If this isn't supposed to run infinitely, you can disable the timer just before calling `Application.SetSuspendState`.

```
    void Main()
    { 
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
        timer.Interval = 30000; //How often you want to show the tooltip?
        timer.Enabled = true;
    }

    void notifyIcon1_BalloonTipClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.SetSuspendState(PowerState.Suspend, false, false);
    }

    void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(10000);
    }
```